# how to perform a count on a column where a value is X

Tags: mysql, sql

is there a way of performing a count operation with SQL where the column equals X 
and ideally a separate count for when the same column equals Y and again for Z?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following (shorter) statement should work for MySQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(val='X'), COUNT(val='Y'), COUNT(val='Z') FROM ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT yourcolumn, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM yourtable
WHERE yourcolumn IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z')
GROUP BY yourcolumn
```

Comment: This is the best option in my opinion (and answered before Yaugen). If the column is indexed this will take advantage of it with index seeks. I am fairly sure performing a sum + "case when" combo will cause a table/index scan which would be much slower over a large amount of data

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ?

```
select
  sum(case when val = 'x' then 1 else 0 end) as countX
  ,sum(case when val = 'y' then 1 else 0 end) as countY
  ,sum(case when val = 'z' then 1 else 0 end) as countZ 
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```
SELECT YourColumn, COUNT(<Any Column of your table>)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY YourColumn
```